# Armijo's algorithm returns a value of alpha too small

Tags: optimization

We've been working in class on optimization methods, and were asked to implement a quasi-Newtonian algorithm to find the minimum of the function: $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ using the *David-Fletcher-Powell* method to approximate the hessian of $f$ and Armijo's rule to find the optimal value of alpha at every step. The following is my python code for the problem:

```
from random import uniform
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo
from time import time
from numdifftools import Gradient



# --------------------------- Objective function: f(x, y) = (x + 1)^2 + y^2 -------------------------------
# number of variables
n_variables = 2

def f(X):
    return (X[0] + 1)**2 + X[1]**2



# --------------------------- Armijou -------------------------------
def armijo(func, X, d):

    # gradient object
    gradient = Gradient(func)

    # argmin function and its derivative
    phi = lambda a: func(X - a * d)
    phi_prime_0 = d.T @ gradient(X)

    # parameters
    epsilon = .6
    eta = 2

    # random starting alpha
    alpha = uniform(0, 1)

    # if condition 3 is verfied
    if phi(alpha) <= phi(0) + (epsilon * phi_prime_0 * alpha):
        while phi(eta * alpha) <= phi(0) + (epsilon * phi_prime_0 * eta * alpha):
            alpha *= eta
    else:
        while phi(alpha) > (epsilon * alpha * phi_prime_0) + phi(0):
            alpha /= eta
    
    return alpha


# --------------------------- Quasi-Newton Method -------------------
def quasi_newton(func, start, finish):
    
    # method parameters
    epsilon = 1e-12
    max_iter = 100

    # gradient object
    gradient = Gradient(func)

    # initial values
    X = [uniform(start, finish) for _ in range(n_variables)]
    g = gradient(X).T
    H = np.identity(n_variables)

    # iteration counter
    iter = 0

    # main loop
    while np.linalg.norm(g) > epsilon and iter < max_iter:
        
        # compute direction
        d = -H @ g

        # find optimal value for alpha
        alpha = armijo(func, X, d)

        # save previous value of X
        old_X = X

        # update values
        X = X - alpha * d
        g = gradient(X).T

        # use DFP to approximate hessian
        y = gradient(X) - gradient(old_X)
        A = alpha * (d @ d.T) / (d.T @ y)
        B = -((H @ y) @ (H @ y).T) / (y.T @ H @ y)
        H = H + A + B

        iter += 1
    
    if iter == max_iter: print("Max iterations reached!")
    return X



# --------------------------- Program -------------------------------
def main():

    # bounds
    low_bound = -100
    high_bound = 100

    # testing method
    print("--------------- Quasi-Newton's Method ---------------------")
    quasi_X = np.zeros((n_variables, 1))
    start = time()
    quasi_X = quasi_newton(f, low_bound, high_bound)
    finish = time()
    quasi_time = finish - start
    print("Minimum:", f(quasi_X))
    print("Found at position:")
    print(quasi_X)
    print("Time: ", quasi_time, " seconds")



# --------------------------- Execution -------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know for a fact that the implementation of the quasi-Newtonian method is working, as when I use *scipy* to find the optimal value of alpha, the algorithm does converge.
The problem arises when I try finding alpha using my implementation of Armijo's rule, as the alpha found is way too small which results in division by zero.